# render() React . Функция для вывода значений свойств

Tags: javascript, reactjs, объекты, render, перебор

У меня есть массив объектов:

```
const arr = [
   {
    a: value1,
    b: value2,
    ..........
              }, 

   {
    a: value1,
    b: value2,
    c: value3,
    .........
              }, 

    {........,
     ........,
     ........,
     ........,
              }
]
```

Количество свойств в каждом объекте меняется, мне нужно отрендерить значения этих свойств в 3 колонки, вот как я это делаю сейчас:

```
render(){
  const columns = arr.map((item) => {
      return(
        <div className={column}>
           {item.a ? <span>{item.a}</span> : ''}
           {item.b ? <span>{item.b}</span> : ''}
           .....................
           .....................
        </div>
      )
    }) 
   }
return(
   {columns}
)
```

Как мне через функцию рендерить тоько те спаны, в которых есть значения, более оптимально и правильнее?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать метод `map` также и с объектом, только вызывать его нужно не для самого объекта, а для его ключей, к-ые можно получить методом [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Кроме того не обязательно сохранять результат `arr.map` в переменной, можно сразу поместить его в `return`.

```
render(){
    return (
        {arr.map((item) => 
            <div className={column}>
                {Object.keys(item).map((key) => 
                    <span>{item[key]}</span> 
                )}
            </div>
        )}
    )
}
```